How can I generalize some bit twiddling operations to all "unsigned" primitive types?
I'm trying to learn something about number traits and want to write some flexible functions for bit-twiddling. This problem fell out of it:
I have defined a few functions that take arguments width and start_bit and return bit-masks of variable types. I start with a zero-valued primitive type, set the first n=width bits to 1 and shift (actually: rotate) everything to the right by start_bit.
Some examples:
# width = 3, start_bit = 6 yields:
# 1000_0011 as u8 (so 1110_0000 rotated 6 times to the right)
# 0000_0011_1000_0000 as u16
# 0000_0011_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000 as u32
# ... and so on

I'd like to know how I can generalize these functions, but I cannot find some needed traits. My functions for u8, u16, u32 and u64 are:
pub fn mask_u8(width: u32, start_bit: u32) -> u8 {
    ((0xFFu8) << (8 - width)).rotate_right(start_bit)
}

pub fn mask_u16(width: u32, start_bit: u32) -> u16 {
    ((0xFFFFu16) << (16 - width)).rotate_right(start_bit)
}

pub fn mask_u32(width: u32, start_bit: u32) -> u32 {
    match width {
        0 => 0,
        32 => u32::MAX,
        width => ((0xFFFFFFFFu32) << (32 - width)).rotate_right(start_bit),
    }
}

pub fn mask_u64(width: u32, start_bit: u32) -> u64 {
    ((0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu64) << (64 - width)).rotate_right(start_bit)
}

When generalizing these functions I have some problems. I need some kind of trait to return the maxmimum number of a specific type e.g. like std::u32::MAX. I could also use std::u32::zero() and invert all bits. But for a generic type T both variants don't work for me, as I cannot find the right traits. Shouldn't there be some traits like Max or something?

You can add your own trait for those, then implement it for all the types you need. For the implementations you can use a macro to avoid the otherwise excessive repetition. For an example, see https://github.com/starblue/lowdim/blob/main/src/integer.rs

To do anything generically, you need a trait. There is no standard library trait that expresses "zero" or "max". You could create your own but the num crate does have traits pre-made for these purposes: Bounded has max_value() and Zero provides zero(). There is also the Unsigned marker trait you can use to constrain against allowing signed types.

Use num-traits for smaller dependency graph.
